# Using new lines in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using

```
$('#'+type+'name'+id).hide().html('ghj').fadeIn(150);
```

Which works fine. But when I use

```
$('#'+type+'name'+id).hide().html('
A lot of html code
').fadeIn(150);
```

The function does not work anymore. Since I want to keep the function tidy I want to put the HTML there in multiple lines. Why doesnt this work?

EDIT:
Still does not work:

```
function Rename(type,id,content){
$('#'+type+'name'+id).hide().html(' '+
    '   <td height=\"20\" valign=\"middle\">'+
    '       <span onclick=\"RenameDo(\'notify\',\''+id+'\',''+content+'')\">'+
    '           <img title=\"Wijzigen\" class=\"LinkImage\" src=\"/common/images/save.png\">'+
    '       </span>'+
    '   </td>'+
    '   <td valign=\"middle\" rowspan=2>&nbsp;fghfgh</td>'+
' ').fadeIn(150);

}
```

Comment: If you don't write the code it's hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: Post your expected HTML output, without all the escaped quotes. Does the function `RenameDo` takes strings as arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `+` to concatenate long strings:

```
$('#'+type+'name'+id).hide().html(' ' + 
'A lot of html code' +
' ').fadeIn(150);
```

Or use `\` to escape newline:

```
$('#'+type+'name'+id).hide().html('\
A lot of html code\
').fadeIn(150);
```

---

**Update**

For the specific string, use this:

```
function Rename(type,id,content){
    $('#'+type+'name'+id).hide().html(' '+
        '   <td height="20" valign="middle">'+
        '       <span onclick="RenameDo(\'notify\',\'' + id + '\',\'' + content + '\')">' +
        '           <img title="Wijzigen" class="LinkImage" src="/common/images/save.png">'+
        '       </span>'+
        '   </td>'+
        '   <td valign="middle" rowspan=2>&nbsp;fghfgh</td>'+
    ' ').fadeIn(150);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So javascript really looks where I put the "enter"? Annoying!

Comment: @Mbrouwer88 Isn't that how every language processes strings?

Comment: Whitespace in strings is significant in PHP as well

Comment: @Mbrouwer88 Is it annoying? I think every language checks it. If you want your code to be clean use
$('#'+type+'name'+id).hide()
.html('A lot of html code').fadeIn(150);

Comment: The slash \ symbol method I understand isn't 100% reliable across browsers so using the + symbol to concatenate is definitely the safest option.

Comment: @pwdst I thought it was reliable... can you provide a reference?

Comment: Using '+' is going to kill your performance in IE7 or older browsers and its not generally a good practice

Comment: I am sorry, still does not work. Please see my answer below (in code notation)

Comment: @JanDvorak I actually got that from other Stack Overflow questions, including one that was no more than a few weeks ago. Google style guides recommend concatenation http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Multiline_string_literals#Multiline_string_literals as the slash technique isn't part of ECMAScript.

Comment: @pwdst the ES5 spec explicitly allows this

Comment: Note that the newline escaping was added in ES5 and won't work in ES3 (read: IE): http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

Comment: Same comment as in @Kolink's answer, the escaped newline method can be pretty risky as any extra whitespace other than a newline immediately following the backslash will cause a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: @JanDvorak I thought I had read somewhere that it was being brought in in ECMAScript 6, although I may be wrong and you're right that it's already included in ECMAScript 5 - I'm not a JavaScript expert. I was simply quoting from the Google document. The debate on the two methods rages if you look at other SO questions and articles on the subject. In either case, the slash method hasn't always been part of the standard and you should take care to test in all browsers you intend to support/receive significant traffic from. Which was my original point.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, the "hack way that works anyway", and the "proper way".

Hack way:

```
$("#"+type+"name"+id).hide().html("\
A lot of html code\
").fadeIn(150)
```

Explanation: By adding a backslash at the end of the line, you are effectively "escaping" the newline so it is ignored instead of an unterminated string constant.

Proper way:

```
$("#"+type+"name"+id).hide().html(
"A lot of html code\n"
+"Just adding some more\n"
+"Because whitespace outside of strings is fine."
).fadeIn(150)
```

Comment: Note the escaped newline is removed, not treated as a newline characted

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it a hack, as long as it's documented.

Comment: It's actually never been defined in any standard, and I think strict mode will fail on it.

Comment: The [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4) allows this explicitly, even in strict mode. `SingleStringCharacter ::`...`\ LineTerminatorSequence`

Comment: Well, that's strange. I remember being told it was non-standard XD

Comment: IMHO, the main problem with the first method -- escaped newlines -- is that any whitespace other than the newline, e.g. spaces, will cause a syntax error. It's pretty easy for extra white space to go unnoticed there.

Comment: [I have found the ES3 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf). It's not valid syntax in ES3 (but it's perfectly valid in ES5)